# How to add some relations to DynamoDB table on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a DynamoDB table called **Posts** in my iOS project on AWS Mobile Services. I would like to add **Favourites** feature to my app, so user can add any post from **Posts** table to favourites. How can I implement it using DynamoDB with AWS Mobile Services? Thank you!

Comment: DynamoDB is not relation based system. Your **Favourites** will have to save unique ID from **Posts** and all this linking will be done on your side.

Answer (score 0):

In NoSQL, the database model is mostly depends on the **Query Access Pattern (QAP)**. I am not sure whether the Mobile front end shows the post and the users who likes it or user page which list their favorite posts.

**Case 1 : Post page showing the users who liked the post**

You can have a `favourites` attribute to `POST` table to have the list of users liked the post.

- favourites - SET or LIST data type

**Example:-**

Post 1 is favorite for user 1 and user 2

```
post 1
favourites : ["user1", "user2" ...]
```